# itemize in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, lists, itemize

When compiling this:

```
   \begin{table*}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|lll|}
        \hline \bfseries Name & \bfseries Opt 1 & \bfseries Opt 2 \\\hline 
        \hline \bfseries Item 1 & X & \\\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Key 
                \item Key 
                \item Key 
            \end{itemize} }        % <--- Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item
         \\ \bfseries Item 2 & X & X \\\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Key key key key key key key key key key key
                \item Key key key key key key key key key key key
                \item Key key key key key key
            \end{itemize} }        % <--- Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item
         \\ \bfseries Item 3 &  & X\\\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Key
             \end{itemize} }       % <--- Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item 
          \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
   \end{table*}
```

The compiler keeps complaining like 20 times or so saying `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item` in marked lines.

This should look like:

```
    +------------------------------+  
    | Name            opt 1  opt 2 |  
    +------------------------------+  
    | Item 1            x     x    |  
    |   * long text with stuff ... |  
    |   * bullte 2                 | 
    |   * and so on                |  
    +------------------------------+  
    | Item 2                  x    | 
    |   * other list               | 
    |   * other list               | 
    +------------------------------+
```

Comment: You can't put a multiline text in a column of type "c". Use the p-type instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this seems to answer the original question perfectly, are there disadvantages to using this method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess that `\parbox` command does the trick. The problem is, that inside a table, you cannot have something that needs "paragraph" line breaking, but inside `\parbox`, you can. You just have to specify the width in advance.

```
   \begin{table*}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|lll|}
        \hline \bfseries Name & \bfseries Opt 1 & \bfseries Opt 2 \\\hline 
        \hline \bfseries Item 1 & X & \\\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Key 
                \item Key 
                \item Key 
            \end{itemize} }}
         \\ \bfseries Item 2 & X & X \\\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Key key key key key key key key key key key
                \item Key key key key key key key key key key key
                \item Key key key key key key
            \end{itemize} }}
         \\ \bfseries Item 3 &  & X\\\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Key
             \end{itemize} }}
          \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
   \end{table*}
```

Comment: Could you add a picture of the output?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variant using cals tables. Borders can be adjusted further, but I like my version.

[image: table with itemize]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{30mm}{20mm}{20mm}}
\makeatletter
\brow
\cell{Name}
\cell{opt 1}
\cell{opt 2}
\erow
\brow
\cell{Item 1}
\cell{x}
\cell{x}
\erow
\def\cals@rs@width{0pt}
\brow
\nullcell{ltb}
\nullcell{tb}
\nullcell{trb}\spancontent{
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Key key key key key key key key key key key
  \item Key key key key key key key key key key key
  \item Key key key key key key
  \end{itemize}
}
\erow
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\brow
\cell{Item 2}
\cell{}
\cell{x}
\erow
\def\cals@rs@width{0pt}
\brow
\nullcell{ltb}
\nullcell{tb}
\nullcell{trb}\spancontent{
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Key key key key key key key key key key key
  \item Key key key key key key key key key key key
  \item Key key key key key key
  \end{itemize}
}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```