# "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup" error

Tags: tables, itemize

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel} % Quotes won't work without babel
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % This is very important!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, breaklinks=true, pdftex=true, raiselinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright}X}

\begin{document}

\subsection{subsection}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YY}\hline

\textbf{Plugin}
&\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth} \vspace{-10pt} \begin{center}         \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{pic.png} \end{center} \vspace{-10pt} \caption{some     caption name} \vspace{-10pt} \end{wrapfigure}
\tabularnewline \hline

See section \textit{section text} for further information\tabularnewline \hline

\textbf{Source Settings}\tabularnewline \hline

\textit{Source:} Choose the Source Type:
\begin{itemize}
\item  Separate 
\item  Side-by-Side 
\item  Top-Bottom \tabularnewline \hline
\end{itemize}

\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I can´t find the mistake, maybe someone could help me with that one, please? I think it has something to do with the itemize environment, but I can´t figure out why.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I have the skills to adeptly fix this issue, however in playing about, I've found that if you take out all the `\tabularnewline \hline` you get something that compiles with no errors.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @E_L: Thanks for the response, but it didn´t work for me, the compiler still says "! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> \egroup".

Comment: Oh well, sorry I couldn't be of more help.  Btw, what typesetting system and tex editor do you use?  I wonder if the reason I got it to work is because I'm using MikTex and TeXnicCenter, and they are maybe configured differently or something?

Comment: The one `\tabularnewline \hline` is *inside* the itemize-environment. Beside this I find the idea to use wrapfig inside a tabular quite curious. What is the idea?

Comment: @E_L: I am using TeXworks. And by the way, you were right, now i deleted the \tabularnewline \hline and it worked, but it didn´t work the first time hmm... but you were right

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: thanks for response, this was it. There is no idea behind it, the code is generated automatically, I just didn´t correct it yet.

Answer (score 2):

see [itemize in a tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48266/itemize-in-a-tabular-environment)

you had already figured that `itemize` was the problem, and a search in google would have taken you to that.

i coded the relevant cell as

```
\begin{parbox}{5cm}
\textit{Source:} Choose the Source Type:
\begin{itemize}
\item  Separate 
\item  Side-by-Side 
\item  Top-Bottom
\end{itemize}
\end{parbox}
```

and it worked.

without your png file, i stuck an inappropriate one of mine in there,
and that highlighted the weirdness of using `wrapfigure` in the table (my png appeared way off to the right); what *were* you aiming to do there?  i would guess that putting *that* in a `parbox`, too, would help -- something like

```
\begin{parbox}{5cm}
\includegraphics{pic.png}
\captionof{figure}{my picture}
\end{parbox}
```

would do the job (but would need `\usepackage{caption}` or `\usepackage{capt-of}`