# Itemize in tabular

Tags: tables, lists, itemize

I really don't get it. I've made e.th. in theory and still it says that I've probably missed "}" somewhere.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage{bpchem}
 \usepackage{times}
 \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
 \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
 \usepackage{hyperref}

 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper, left=25mm, right=20mm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
 \newcommand{\degreeCelsius}{\ensuremath{\,^{\circ}\mathrm{C}}\xspace}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{ll}
 {\footnotesize Single-Photon Polymerization (1-PP):} &  {\footnotesize Two-Photon      Polymerization (2-PP):} \\
 {\footnotesize 
 \begin{itemize}
 \item UV-light irradiation
 \item restricted to the surface
 \end{itemize}} 
 & 
 {\footnotesize
 \begin{itemize}
 \item NIR-laser irradiation
 \item pulses focused into the volume of the resin
 \item condition: certain photon density value to be exceeded
 \end{itemize}}
 \\
 \end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use `itemize` in an `l` column, because there won't be line breaks. You need a `p` column.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114822/itemize-inside-longtable where `longtable` is used, but the problem is just the same.

Comment: I've duped to one of the suggestions: both it and [itemize in a tabular environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48266/itemize-in-a-tabular-environment would potentially be suitable)